# Can't tab lists, but can backspace or shift-tab them in word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, outline, indent

I am trying to have an outline follow the format

1. List item (with a subsection under this one)
2. List item
3. List item

However, word isn't letting me "tab" to create subsection. I can backspace and shift tab to reverse the outline process. I have tried going into autoformat as you type and the box is checked next to "set left and first indents with tab and backspace".

Screenshot:
[image: List]

Comment: After the **1. List item** you want to press Enter (this will continue the list and insert "2."). From there just press Tab. You should have a subsection for "1."

Comment: @zain.ali I have tired that and it worked before (previous pages) but it isn't working now...

Comment: Have you reached the level limit? How many levels in are you?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change the list level.

[image: Change List Level]

Comment: I have tried that too. It messes up the **List 1** items so instead of going 1. then sub text 2. then subtext; it goes 1. subtext 1. subtext 1. subtext. It doesn't register the "main" list

Comment: Could you add some screenshots to the post? Don't worry if you can't embed them. The links will be fine or we can edit them in for you.

Comment: I am sorry! It wont let me inset a picture...something about 10 reputation "points" needed...is there any other way to send you one?